# Templates para Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, front-end, template

Estou iniciando um sistema que vai ser a base de todos os sistemas da empresa.

O sistema irei desenvolver em Laravael 4 e a interface será um tema do `wrapbootstrap`.

Quais seriam as melhores práticas para usar o meu layout como library/package para os meus futuros projetos?

Comment: Recomendo utilizar este plugin para gerenciamento de templates: https://github.com/teepluss/laravel-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já fiz o que você está fazendo algumas vezes e no meu caso achei melhor picotar todo o tema, cada pedaço correspondente há algum elemento do layout(header,footer,sidebar etc..) desta forma fica melhor para reaproveitar apenas usando o @include('') então na maioria das vezes minha estrutura fica assim:

```
views
--layouts
----master.blade.php(estrutura do html)
----partials
------sidebar.blade.php
------header.blade.php
------footer.blade.php
------styles.blade.php
------scripts.blade.php
------navigation.blade.php
------alerts.blade.php
```

Comment: Cara, interessante, no caso não teria como criar uma librarie ou package? Outra coisa, para facilitar na hora de atualizar para o L5 e nova versão do layout? É melhor usar Form ou o código puro html?

Comment: Estava aqui pensando também, se teria como definir o layout no controller geral, em vez de definir em cada view usando o "use".

Answer (score 0):

O que resolvi:

seguindo a idéia de Richard segue minha estrutura:

```
views
--layouts
----master.blade.php(estrutura do html)
----sections (alteração minha)
------sidebar.blade.php
------header.blade.php
------footer.blade.php
------styles.blade.php
------scripts.blade.php
------navigation.blade.php
------content.blade.php (será usado para carregar a view que a rota definir)
------alerts.blade.php
```

Minha dúvida final era se poderia definir um template para um controller ao invés de usar o USE em cada view. Segue a resposta para a minha dúvida:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

/**
 * The layout that should be used for responses.
 */
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

/**
 * Show the user profile.
 */
public function showProfile()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
}
```

}

Valeu pessoal.